# Recursive Type Lensing

Tags: haskell, grammar, lenses, scrap-your-boilerplate

I'm trying to create some code that can take **any** recursive grammar data type and any expression of that data type and produce a list of all sub-expressions of the same type, built up, kind of like a `scan` on the recursion of the type.

I've written two manual examples below for an accompanying toy calculator grammar type `EExp`. The first example uses prisms and lenses from the Lens library and will only work on the one `eg1` example expression, whereas the second function just uses handrolled code but will work on any `EExp` expression.

Ideally I could use template haskell or something else to automatically build a recursive function that could focus on each of the sub expressions of an expression of any kind in that type (like a prism/lens), and therefore also easily print out a list of all the pieces of any expression given to it.

I'm a little bit stuck, though, with what to try or research next. Any help is really appreciated!

```
import qualified Control.Lens as Lens
import qualified Control.Lens.TH as LTH


-- Syntax for toy language

data EExp a
  = ELit a
  | EAdd (EExp a) (EExp a)
  | EMul (EExp a) (EExp a)
  | ESub (EExp a) (EExp a)
  deriving Show

-- build out a set of focus functions using lens / TH

LTH.makePrisms ''EExp


-- An example "text" in the Syntax

eg1 :: EExp Int
eg1 = EAdd
        (ELit 1)
        (EAdd (ELit 2) (ELit 0))

-- using lenses, we build out all the
-- EExp possibilities from the example "text":

lensedOptions :: Show a => EExp a -> [EExp a]
lensedOptions exp =
  let
    maybeGet l = Lens.preview l exp
    listMaybes =
      [ Just exp
      , maybeGet (_EAdd.(Lens._1))
      , maybeGet (_EAdd.(Lens._2))
      , maybeGet (_EAdd.(Lens._2)._EAdd.(Lens._1))
      , maybeGet (_EAdd.(Lens._2)._EAdd.(Lens._2))
      ]
  in
    maybe [] id $ sequenceA listMaybes

printEm :: IO ()
printEm = sequence_ $ map print $ lensedOptions eg1

-- using handwritten code, we build out all the
-- EExp possibilities from the example "text":


buildOptions :: Show a => EExp a -> [EExp a]
buildOptions exp =
  let
    buildBinOpts e1 e2 = [exp] ++ buildOptions e1 ++ buildOptions e2
  in
    case exp of
      ELit i -> [exp]
      EAdd e1 e2 ->
        buildBinOpts e1 e2
      EMul e1 e2 ->
        buildBinOpts e1 e2
      ESub e1 e2 ->
        buildBinOpts e1 e2

printEm2 :: IO ()
printEm2 = sequence_ $ map print $ buildOptions eg1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeking the [Control.Lens.Plated](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html) module.

First add a `Data` derivation:

```
{-# language DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Data.Lens
import Control.Lens -- for universeOf function

data EExp a
  = ELit a
  | EAdd (EExp a) (EExp a)
  deriving (Show, Data)
```

Then:

```
> buildOptions eg1
[EAdd (ELit 1) (EAdd (ELit 2) (ELit 0)),ELit 1,EAdd (ELit 2) (ELit 0),ELit 2,ELit 0]

> universeOf uniplate eg1
[EAdd (ELit 1) (EAdd (ELit 2) (ELit 0)),ELit 1,EAdd (ELit 2) (ELit 0),ELit 2,ELit 0]
```

The `uniplate` lens is doing the bulk of the magic here; using the information provided by the [`Data` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data), it is able to walk one step into any `Data`-friendly data structure to find self-similar children. It is also doing [some high-altitude caching gymnastics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/src/Data.Data.Lens.html#Oracle) to make the traversals efficient, but we can safely ignore that.

`universeOf uniplate` repeatedly calls `uniplate` to find all transitive descendants.

For more information on `Data.Data`, check out the [Scrap Your Boilerplate paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.958&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Lämmel and SPJ.

Comment: Awesome! <3 Thank you so much @haoformayor . I'll definitely read that paper soon (I think I had an attempt a couple of times when I was originally looking into generic programming in haskell out of interest, but it was more a cursory interested gloss than anything).

Comment: According to my GHC, the extension is called `DeriveDataTypeable`, actually. I'll correct what you wrote.

Comment: Also, I can't get the code you wrote to work. Did you try to compile it before you answered? I guess I accepted your answer a bit prematurely, because I should have tried it myself first. Only getting to that now. I wonder if you maybe meant `universeOf`? I need to study this more.

Comment: Yeah, you meant `universeOf`. I'll adjust the code again.